# Having trouble adding update method to Symbol

Tags: scala

I am attempting to add an update method to the Symbol class.

```
class SymbolUpdate(s: Symbol) {
    def update(i: Int) = s.name + i
}
implicit def toSymbolUpdate(s: Symbol) = new SymbolUpdate(s)
```

But when I run the code I get the following

```
scala> 's = 1
<console>:327: error: value update is not a member of object Symbol
              's = 1
              ^
```

But it does work when I call the method directly.

```
scala> 's.update(1)
res41: java.lang.String = s1
```

Or if I explicitly put an empty argument array.

```
scala> 's() = 1
res42: java.lang.String = s1
```

Not sure what the problem is with my code?

Comment: My impression was that a single argument apply method still requires the explicit empty argument list. I've spent some time searching the internet for counter-examples, but to no avail. Are you sure that what you are asking for is valid? (It's not the implicit that's failing because an explicit instantiation of SymbolUpdate in 2.9.1 can also not be updated without the empty arg list).

Comment: I'm really curious as to what you're trying to accomplish here. Normally `update` is used to modify a mutable container, such as `Array`. Here `update` modifies nothing, and just returns a `String`.

Comment: I am creating a DSL where there are "variables" that are assigned values and this creates a model of such activity.  In this case, a Symbol is contrived to represent the variable in my DSL.   The example is not meant to be representative of my use.  Just needed it to do something to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Scala Language Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> An assignment `f(args) = e` with a function application to the left of the ‘=’ operator is interpreted as `f.update(args, e)`, i.e. the invocation of an `update` function
>   deﬁned by `f`.

It's especially clear if you read the corresponding section in [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala):

> Similarly, when an assignment is made to a variable to which parenthesis and one or more arguments have been applied, the compiler will transform that into an invocation of an update methods that takes the arguments in parenthesis as well as the object to the right of the equals sign.

Together, I take it to mean that the parenthesis are required.

Comment: Yes, sadly that is what I interpret as well.  I am trying to do a DSL and the extra parenthesis detract from a usability point of view.  Thx

Comment: In your DSL, you could define a new operator that looks a lot like equals. `implicit def addColonEquals(s: Symbol) = new { def :=(i: Int) = s.name + i }`.

Comment: Yes, that is likely the route for me to take.  Thanks for suggesting it!